# Sudo vs Su with specific usage on Debian

Tags: debian, sudo, su

Are:

`sudo -i` and `su -` functionally the same, both should give fresh root shells with root's environment right?

If so are `sudo -s` and `su` the same?

Thanks

Comment: Relevant, maybe even a dupe: [Is there ever a good reason to run sudo su?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218169)

Comment: Also possible dupe: [What is the difference between 'sudo' and 'su -c'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16334)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for `sudo` you use your password. For `su` you use `root` user password.